# Excel Filter, but Do Not Allow Sort

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that I am working on, which will create a unique letter & number combination, based on the number of occurrences of the same value in Column E. This works great, except if someone sorts the rows, then the letter & numbers in Column A, recalculate. I would like for users to be able to filter the list, but just not sort it.

Alternatively if the values in column A could somehow be static once calculated, then it wouldn't matter.

Is there a better way that I should be approaching this?
[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot 1]

[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

I can not really see your pictures but did you try to make it a pivot on a second sheet and insert a "calculated field" if needed? This usually works. They can even filter and sort it this way if the formula stys the same for all rows.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't worked with Pivot tables before, but in what I am seeing looking at them now, I'm not sure it would work for this use. The lists I am wanting to filter will ultimately be created by the user. This is a template file to be filled out dynamically across multiple sheets in the workbook, so the list on this table is compiling data through dropdown lists from the other sheets. The user can drag or copy the lines down, to add more rows.

Comment: Can you send me an example file and a description what you need it to do exactly? I can try to find a solution.

Comment: Here is a sample file. The Master Index tab is the one I am looking at.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ba6r7axcobyglpv/Prelay%20Log.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: I think a macro would probably work, one that does essentially the same thing as the formula currently in the cell. But I would want it to look for empty cells in column A, as users may add rows over time. If they need to renumber an existing row, they can delete the value in column A and rerun the macro.

Comment: This solved it for me: http://www.onlinepclearning.com/advanced-filters-in-userforms/